# Wildcard search using percentage

Tags: c#, regex, wildcard

I have the following example code in linqpad. Copy/paste into linqpad and select Language c# statements to run this.

Currently 'AB%C' only matches AB C, I want % to match zero or more characters like in SQL.

```
// Define Stock Items
List<StockItem> stockItems = new List<StockItem>();

stockItems.Add(new StockItem{
Id = 0,
Code = "444B",
Description = "AB C"
});

stockItems.Add(new StockItem{
Id = 0,
Code = "11221",
Description = "ABC"
});

// Regex Search of Stock Items
string searchString = "AB%C";
string regexSearch = searchString
                 .Replace("*", ".+")
                 .Replace("%", ".+")
                 .Replace("#", "\\d")
                 .Replace("@", "[a-zA-Z]")
                 .Replace("?", "\\w");
Regex regex = new Regex(regexSearch);

List<StockItem> results;
results = stockItems.Where(s => regex.IsMatch(s.Description)).ToList();

results.Dump();

} // Bracket defines end of logic so we can declare classes next

// StockItem Class
internal class StockItem
{ 
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Code {get; set;}
public string Description {get; set;}
// } Don't close class for linqpad!
```

I am obtained the regex from [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814084/c-sharp-linq-how-to-handle-wildcard-search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` means "one or more", you need `*` instead which is "zero or more":

```
.Replace("%", ".*")
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei - I'll have to brush up on regex I think